# How to use canny correctly?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, canny-operator

I have an image with a resolution of 2560x1920. I am applying the canny operator to it. But the result I am getting doesn’t suit me. I want all the edges to stand out. However, when I apply this algorithm to images of lower resolution, everything works correctly. How can I solve the problem?

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("index (2).jpg", 0)
can = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 150)
cv2.imshow("res", can)
cv2.imwrite("res.jpg", can)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original image:
[image: Original image]

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: For debugging: Compute Sobel Gradient with same thresholds used by Canny and have a look at those gradients, whether you can expect Canny to find your desired structure there.

Comment: Canny is a very basic function. Probably it wont be the solution for your task.

Comment: @Micka thanks for the answer! tell me what can i use for edge detection?

Comment: In your case a hsv hue + saturation thresholding might work great

Comment: If you have to deal with a lot of different uncontrolled real world scenes you might want to train a DNN for segmentation (either instance seg or dense seg).

Comment: If you really want edge detection, give lineSegmentDetector a try.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem!

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("index (2).jpg", 0)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (25, 25), 0, sigmaY=0)
can = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150, apertureSize=5, L2gradient=True)
cv2.imshow("res", can)
cv2.imwrite("res.jpg", can)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zYSo.jpg)